# Need help in URL rewriting sub-domains

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently registered a domain name kbcsurveyors.com. Then, I created two sub-domains, which created two new folders in the root folder.

[image]

My motive is that if I type ***kbcsurveyors.com/preinspection***, it should point to ***preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com***. Same for other sub domains.

In my **.htaccess**, which I placed inside root of mydomainname.com, I have written following lines:

```
RewriteEngine  On                                     
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^preinspection/(.*)$          https://kbcsurveyors.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]    # Handle requests for "Preinspection"
```

But this file structure does not work. How do I write the .htaccess file to achieve what I want?

[image]

Regards

**EDIT**

I have asked a fresh question as this one has been messed up. Here is the link:[How to rewrite rules for sub-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195242/how-to-rewrite-rules-for-sub-domains)

Comment: Please, don't change the whole question, this invalidates all current answers. If you have new or more specific facts, add them below a horizontal rule `---`, or prefix with an "Edit" or "Update".

Comment: My Apologies, Olaf. I will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub-domain1.mydomainname.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomainname.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: It did not work. "Internal Server Error" was thrown. Even tried moving the. htaccess file to httpdocs folder. In fact, whole website went down with "Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect requests for a subdirectory to the appropriate domain, you can use the rules you have (or similar), but need to specify the scheme `http://` and may use the [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

```
RewriteRule ^sub-domain1 http://sub-domain1.mydomainname.com [R,NC,L]
```

If you also want to forward the requested path, you must capture it and use in the target

```
RewriteRule ^sub-domain1/(.*)$ http://sub-domain1.mydomainname.com/$1 [R,NC,L]
```