# How to rewrite rules for sub-domains

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently registered a domain name kbcsurveyors.com. Then, I created two sub-domains, which created two new folders in the root folder.

[image]

My motive is that if I type ***kbcsurveyors.com/preinspection***, it should point to ***preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com***. Same for other sub domains.

In my **.htaccess**, which I placed inside root of mydomainname.com, I have written following lines:

```
RewriteEngine  On                                     
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^preinspection/(.*)$          https://kbcsurveyors.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]    # Handle requests for "Preinspection"
```

But this file structure does not work.

[image]

How do I write the .htaccess file to achieve what I want?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment out your existing rule.

Create a new file `preinspection/.htaccess` with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^preinspection\.kbcsurveyors\.com$ [NC]
RewriteEngine .* http://preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com/$0 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for super-quick reply. It still throws Internal Server Error. I have placed the .htaccess file inside **httpdocs** folder.

Comment: As I mentioned, this should be placed in `preinspection/.htaccess`. Also check your Apache error.log to know why it is throwing 500 error

Comment: Oops! Sorry. You were right. It was too be placed in **preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com** directory. But now, it says "404 Not Found". Worse, I have never used .htaccess file before, so I am kinda unable to debug .htaccess files.

Comment: When you rename this .htaccess to something else, does `http://preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com` work fine?

Comment: After renaming, it works. But, before renaming, **preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com** throws error 500 and **kbcsurveyors.com/preinspection** throws error 404. Also, I have bought SSL for this domain. So, the protocol is **https** and not **http**.

Comment: `http://preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com` works for me as well. Without you getting access to apache error.log showing cause of 500 error it is difficult for anyone to help your with just the guess work.

Comment: Found logs with all sorts of Errors Codes and Warnings. Now what should I look for in Logs?

Comment: OK. The error message for error 500 is "Error: Unable to display the file /var/www/vhosts/kbcsurveyors.com/preinspection.kbcsurveyors.com/favicon.ico: Unsupported file format.".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139892/discussion-between-anubhava-and-kush-impetus).